# Convergence of derivatives of $\sum c_{k} \phi_{k}e^{-\lambda_{k}t}$ eigenfunction expansion

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

**Q**: Is the  $\sum c_{k} \phi_{k}(z)e^{-\lambda_{k}t}$ smooth over $\Omega\times (0,\infty)$ (both z and t),  where $\Delta \phi_{k}+\lambda_{k}\phi_{k}=0$ for bounded domain $\Omega$ and $|c_{k}|\leq k$? From elliptic theory we have $\phi_{k}\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$, so the above should be valid.

**Side question**: Do we have uniform bounds for derivatives of $\phi_{k}(z)$ i.e.

$$\sup_{z\in \Omega}|D^{(n)}\phi_{\lambda}(z)|\leq c(\lambda) |D^{(n)}\phi_{\lambda}|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\leq b(\lambda)?$$

**Attempt**

One way is proving that $\sum c_{k} \phi_{k}(z)e^{-\lambda_{k}t}$ satisfies the heat equation with zero boundary. To do that we need uniform summable bound on derivatives

$$|c_{k} \Delta\phi_{k}(z)e^{-\lambda_{k}t}|\leq B_{k}$$

$$|c_{k} \phi_{k}(z)\partial_{t}e^{-\lambda_{k}t}|\leq D_{k}$$

We have 
$$sup_{z\in \Omega}|\phi_{\lambda}(z)|\leq c_{d}\lambda^{\frac{d-1}{4}}|\phi_{\lambda}|_{L^{2}(D)}=c_{d}\lambda^{\frac{d-1}{4}}$$

since $\phi_{\lambda}$ are $L^{2}$-orthonormal. And so using $\Delta \phi_{k}(z)=-\lambda_{k}\phi_{k}(z)$ and weyl $\lambda_{k}\approx k$ we obtain a uniform bound if instead we work with domain $\Omega\times [\varepsilon,\infty)$:

$$\sup_{(z,t)\in \Omega\times [\varepsilon,\infty)}|\sum c_{k}(-\lambda_{k})\phi_{k}(z)e^{-\lambda_{k}t}|\leq \sum k^{c}e^{-k\cdot \varepsilon} <\infty$$

However, I had to use smaller domain.

Comment: Uniform in $k$? It's not clear exactly what your question is, could you make it more precise?

Comment: I assume you want smoothness in $x$, but do you intend $t>0$? Without $t>0$ you don't have good decay properties to force the sum to converge. Also, why should $\lambda_k$ be $O(k)$? Under "typical" circumstances it is $O(k^2)$.